Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi } \log ^{n}\left(2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right) \, dt$ where n is a natural number
Could someone suggest a general approach e.g. a recursive approach or a summation formula for computing these integrals? I got these results from the Wolfram website.


I can tell for the case n=1

I could compute for n = 1, 2, and 3, and added those to the list

Not sure if that leads to something practical, but you could use the fact that $$\ln\left(2\sin\left( \frac t 2\right)\right)=-\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\cos (kt)}k$$ and expand the power into a multinomial sum of terms of the form $$\frac{\cos(k_1)\cos(k_2)\dots\cos(k_n)}{k_1 k_2\dots k_n}$$

With a high accuracy,
$$\int_0^{\pi } \log ^{n}\left(2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right) , dt\approx(-1)^nn!$$
even for a small $n\sim 1$. For example, already for $n=5$ the difference is lower than $0.1$%
$$\int_0^{\pi } \log ^5\left(2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)dt=-119.885 \approx-5!=-120$$

Maybe you can define $I(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi}log^{n}(2a\sin(t/2))dt$. Differentiate under the integral sign and try to use a recursion for  $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cot^{n}(\alpha)d\alpha$.

Just in case :) For any $0<a<e$
$$\int_0^{\pi } \log ^{n}\left(a \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right) , dt\approx(-1)^n\frac2an!$$

The value is given by $\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial a^n}\frac{2^a \left(\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)}$ and taking the $a\to 0$ limit.

I can verify that @Covariant's formula is correct

Use exponential generating functions. Let $I_n=\int_0^\pi\log^n\big(2\sin(t/2)\big)\,dt$, then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n\frac{z^n}{n!}=\int_0^\pi\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)^z\,dt=\frac{\pi\ \Gamma(1+z)}{\Gamma^2(1+z/2)}=\pi\ e^{g(z)},
$$
where, using the Dirichlet eta-function $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$,
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\eta(n)z^n\impliedby\color{gray}{\log\Gamma(1+z)=-\gamma z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\zeta(n)z^n}.
$$
Thus, the values of $I_n$ can be computed using exponentiation of a series (and the values of $\eta$).

Thanks. While I did not compute the exponentiation, I did verify that we can get the result from the integral in the first equation: $\underset{z\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial a^n}\frac{\pi  \Gamma (z+1)}{\Gamma
\left(1+\frac{z}{2}\right)^2}$. This is similar to @Covariant's approach.

Converting it into a Beta function as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\int_0^\pi\left[2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right]^a d t \\
& =2^a \int_0^\pi \sin ^a\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) d t \\
& =2^{a+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^a t d t \\
& =2^{a+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-1} t \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} t dt \\
& =2^a B\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Via Leibniz’ Rule, differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ by $n$ times at $a=0$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n & =\left.\frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left[2^a B\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\right|_{a=0} \\
& =\left.\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(2^a\right)^{(n-k)} B^{(k)}\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{a=0}  \\
& =\left.\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \ln ^{n-k} 2 B^{(k)}\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{a=0}
\end{aligned}
$$
which is the best I can do.
